# Powershell: is there a Scope Preference for Variables?

Tags: powershell, variables, scope, preferences

Morning guys, hopefully just a quick one. Is there a Scope Preference for Variables like there is for some other settings (`$ErrorActionPreference`, etc)?
I'm working on a script that has a bunch of functions that call on information created in each other and I'm just looking to avoid writing `$Script:` or `$Global:` in front of each variable everytime *(I'm being lazy I know)*

Comment: No. If you want fewer scope modifiers in your variable expressions: design your functions so that you minimize variable access across scopes :)

Comment: *"a bunch of functions that call on information created in each other"* Setting up and using piping help

Comment: As above, design the script so you minimise the need to scope. Define variables at the start/in the main body so that they are available by default. Then only scope as necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a Scope Preference for Variables like there is for some other settings (`$ErrorActionPreference`, etc)?

No, scoping behavior is part of the language's core runtime semantics and is *not* configurable.

> I'm working on a script that has a bunch of functions that call on information created in each other and I'm just looking to avoid writing `$Script:` or `$Global:` in front of each variable everytime

You don't need it *everytime* - you only need the scope modifier when you're *writing* to a parent scope.

Resolution of variables for reading will fall back through parent scopes and eventually the global scope, until a matching variable is found:

```
# variable defined at script scope, functions defined in here will fall back to resolving this when `$Config` is referenced
$Config = @{
  'setting' = 'initialValue'
}

function Update-Config {
  # Scope modifier is only necessary when "writing up" through the scope stack
  $script:Config = @{
    setting = 'updatedValue'
  }
}

function Do-Stuff {
  $setting = $Config['setting'] # no need to use script: here

  Write-Host "About to do something with '$setting'"
}

Do-Stuff
Update-Config
Do-Stuff
```

Executing the above in a script file will print:

```
About to do something with 'initialValue'
About to do something with 'updatedValue'
```

Note that for functions bound to a module, the `script:` scope is shared across the module - writing to `$script:Variable` in one module function will cause resolution of non-local `$Variable` to resolve correctly in any other function in the same module

For more information about scoped variable resolution, consult [the `about_Scopes` help file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes)